# Change the location of subtitles in jwplayer?

Tags: jwplayer

In jwplayer, you can easily add [subtitles with styles](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1482067-styling-captions-for-fcc-compliance).

For example, this is a video with subtitles:[image]

The problem is that you can't see all the subtitles sometimes due to the location of the player.

Is there a way I can change the location of the subtitles and levitate them a bit from the playing bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my solution, well at least for HTML5, you can add in your css this:

> .jwcaptions{    top:-20px!important; }

Change -20px to -100px to position the position of the subtitles!

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer : I remember in old jwplayer we can bring controls to bottom but it is not available in new version . I wish we could use that API once again and bring jwplayer control to bottom

Comment: Yes, I am ware of that. In JW6, the controls are always over.